# Navigation Stack Localisation Method

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, path-planning, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it necessary to use AMCL in order to localise and path plan in the navigation stack?

I have a good estimate of the position of my robot in the map from using a kinect and RGBDSLAM. Can I just use this somehow or do I need to localise again using laser data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12996/navigation-stack-localisation-method/) by [jwrobbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1711/jwrobbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle you can use any localization method you want.
During navigation you just have to look out for how stable and accurate it is.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1